# How secure is OAuth2 for web applications

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

Let’s consider a single page client side application, developed using HTML and Javascript.

In this case, even if the implicit or authentication code flow is being used to request Access Tokes, still the clientID and Secret would still be found in some Javascript, which might be making the token requests. Plus, passing the Access Token in the request header (or query parameter) are still visible in the network trace. Moreover the Access Token needs to be stored locally in a browser.

- How secure it is to use OAuth2 for web based applications??
- How the user information can be protected, if the client (browser) is compromised.

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011649/1235935 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53988717/1235935

Answer (score 3):

For implicit OAuth, you don't use a Client Secret in the browser javascript. You only need the Client ID. The Client ID is not a secret and is considered public information. The Client ID and Scopes identify what permissions to services you wish to authorize.

> How secure it is to use OAuth2 for web based applications??

OAuth itself is very secure. However, as with any security implementation, it is only as strong as the weakest component. For implicit grant flow, such as your single page web application, the authentication occurs between the user and the Identity provider. Once the flow completes your app has an Access Token and optionally a Client ID Token. The assumption with implicit grant flow is that the user is present at the browser and that no confidential information will be stored.

> How the user information can be protected, if the client (browser) is
>   compromised?

If the user's browser is compromised, nothing can be protected. Once an OAuth token has been generated that has permissions to do `X`, the compromised browser can continue to do `X` until the token expires.

If your question is about protecting the user's login and password, or other type of authentication information then this information is also at risk if the browser is compromised.

In summary a compromised browser potentially has no security no matter what technology is used for authentication and authorization.