# LocalStorage value resets on a different page

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have multiple pages like Home, Faq and more and I've added darkmode function and I want website to remember the choice. If I have pressed darkmode on home and refresh the choice is saved. However when I go to Faq the value is reset even tho I've pasted the same code on my other website. Yes I've tried connecting same JS file to these 2 websites and didn't worked.

btw it's shortened code as example so don't mind that

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (element.style.color == "wheat") {
        element.style.color = "rgb(33,33,36)";
        window.localStorage.setItem("mode", "White");
    } else {
        element.style.color = "wheat"
        window.localStorage.setItem("mode", "Dark");
    }
});

var ls = localStorage.getItem("mode");

if (ls == "Dark") {
    console.log("it's dark");
} else {
    console.log("it's white");
}
```

So yeah if I click the button and refresh website it will be "it's dark" but if I click and go to Faq with same connected js file it will be "it's white". Sorry if it's a stupid question I'm still learning and I'm not sure if it should work with multiple pages maybe I should use different method like cookies? Thanks for any help.

Comment: All pages in the same domain should share the same local storage. It has nothing to do with the JS file.

Comment: But if you have different subdomains, they each have their own local storage. So `www.example.com` and `faq.example.com` are separate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997063/how-to-share-localstorage-among-different-subdomains

Comment: Are you serving the site or just testing with static files?

Comment: Yes I'm testing those websites from a local files.

Comment: @someone Share the link/URL to Home and FAQ.